# Assertion in the Ignite code

Tags: ignite, gridgain

Does somebody know what these logs mean when using Ignite?

[23:07:54] (err) Failed to notify listener: o.a.i.i.processors.cache.distributed.near.GridNearTxLocal$4@d4b2353java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.GridDistributedCacheEntry.checkThreadChain(GridDistributedCacheEntry.java:838)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.GridDistributedCacheEntry.removeLock(GridDistributedCacheEntry.java:441)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheEntry.removeLock(GridDhtCacheEntry.java:319)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.GridDistributedCacheEntry.txUnlock(GridDistributedCacheEntry.java:783)

---

03.21.2017 23:07:54.476 [sys-#18%geos%] ERROR DLSlackBotTeamSocket - Error for Slack team: local-datalingvo
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.GridDistributedCacheEntry.checkOwnerChanged(GridDistributedCacheEntry.java:808) ~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtCacheEntry.addDhtLocal(GridDhtCacheEntry.java:257) ~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtLockFuture.addEntry(GridDhtLockFuture.java:392) ~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.GridDhtTransactionalCacheAdapter.lockAllAsyncInternal(GridDhtTransactionalCacheAdapter.java:753) ~[ignite-core-1.7.0.jar:1.7.0]

Comment: Resolved. I started Ignite transaction directly from cache listener thread. It was wrong. But Ignite behavior still seems strange. Exception with detailed explanation would be better than current  assertion.